# How to transfer large file between me and my friend?

Tags: software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free way to share large files over the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/121995/free-way-to-share-large-files-over-the-internet)
>   [Transfering large files over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/300539/transfering-large-files-over-internet)

Are there some utilities, which allow to transfer files from peer to peer at full channel speed, like torrent clients or download manages do?

I.e. I want to send big file to my friend for free.

The main feature is transferring with multiple channels simultaneosly.

Comment: Newsgroup/private torrent/e-mail/private FTP - there are many solutions, not many of the free web based ones will operate at maximum speed. The one's i've listed have the capacity to do so if available :)

Comment: How big is big?

Comment: what OS are the two of you using so we can give you actual software solutions.

Comment: And http://superuser.com/questions/119044/best-method-of-transferring-files-over-internet , http://superuser.com/questions/121995/free-way-to-share-large-files-over-the-internet , http://superuser.com/questions/154753/best-way-to-transfer-huge-files-over-internet and more.

Answer (score 1):

For one-time use, the simplest solution to get working is the file-transfer feature of a chat program.  Let it run overnight.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple channel transfer only works when you are transferring either to or from multiple peers. For example, in the case of a fully seeded Torrent, you're downloading from sometimes hundreds of different sources, each one giving only relatively small amount of data and using a relatively low amount of bandwidth. All those small bits coming together into your computer at once results in a very high speed download only at your end.

If you're transferring a file between yourself and a friend, you're probably only looking at one computer at either end, so you will not get the multiple-peer, maximum bandwidth utilization of a popular Torrent.

So if you can't get the multi-channel, you're left with "free" and probably hopefully easy.

In this case you'll need to configure your firewall and router, and probably install software to facilitate the transfer.

The most mature and direct method that doesn't require any third party apps or cloud hosting will be FTP.

Using a free tool such as FileZilla (which is multiplatform and free), which is an FTP client that also has a fully functional FTP server, you can "host" the file on one computer and allow the other computer to connect and move or copy the file using the maximum available bandwidth of the **slowest connection of the two**.

However, as alluded to earlier, personal firewalls and routers and modems block this sort of thing normally because FTP servers open to the internet are not usually things you want on an average user's computer. So you'll need to configure your firewall and router and probably modem to allow this transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I used to share my file/volume with FTP, but due to firewalls, proxies and whatsnot that people sit behind its usually quite tricky to get it working. Ever since torrent became an option I have used that successfully in pretty much any thinkable situation, and its always worked great for me and my friends.

Answer (score 0):

if the files is truly huge and your connection is not capable of handling sustained 1-5MBs, it might be faster to burn it onto a CD and simply mail it. Low-tech approach but it's still relevant!